# Remove assets from album expo react native

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using expo-media-library to read assets from albums
but to remove assets on android the expo go app shows an android confirmation modal. but is not deleted from storage.

[image]

as docs mention [Android it keeps all copies of them (album is strictly connected to the asset)](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/media-library/#medialibrarydeleteassetsasyncassets). Is there any way to delete assets.

for now, I am moving assets to the temp album and delete the temp album. but it shows confirmation modal twice. Is there any better way for deletion.

Comment: I've been facing the same issue on Android based devices for the last 4 Expo version (43, 44, 45 and 46). So far, I have not been able to find a workaround. Using the same code on iOS, it functions as expected. I have also tried to ensure all copies are removed from albums and deleting the asset, but the asset is never removed. The oddest part is that the function returns true, indicating a successful delete. Have you had any success with a workaround other than what is stated?

Comment: I was making an example using expo-media-library, for now, I have kept it aside. 
Also, docs explicitly mention about assets not being removal on android. The only workaround seems for now on expo is to create an album move assets to the album and delete the album

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding your exact problem, but when using the `MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync()`, you can delete the asset that is created with `MediaLibrary.deleteAssetsAsync()`.

Some things to note that may not be immediately obvious is that `.deleteAssetsAsync()` requires the asset(s) to be in a list, and you need to pass the entire asset object, not just the URI for said object or you may encounter a `Could not delete file` error.

```
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';


const { uri } = await this.camera.takePictureAsync();
const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(uri);

// Do stuff with asset
try {
  await MediaLibrary.deleteAssetsAsync([asset]);
} catch (error) {
  // Error handling
}
```